# Who is the original author/creator that took the time to fill/create Northwind SQL server sample database?

Tags: sql-server

I've used it before, but I never really seen any documentation in SQL server pointing to who actually created it. Is it a person, a group of people? Did Microsoft create it? Who??

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there were several members of the SQL Server team that had input into Northwind. I could probably name 5 or 6 people that I know personally who were on that team then, but I won't. Because who cares? Most of the people on the team at the time are no longer on the team, or if they are, have much different roles today.

I don't think this is a relevant or constructive question here. What are you going to do with this information even if someone knows the answer, and you have some way to verify it (like call these people at home)?